# np Select Rows that Match Edning

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy 2-D array with rows as observations and columns as covariates. I would like to select the rows that match a specified example of the last *n* columns. For example with n=2:

`A = [[0,1,0],[3,0,1],[5,1,0]]` with `target=[1,0]` would return `B = [[0,1,0],[5,1,0]]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[0,1,0],[3,0,1],[5,1,0]])
target = [1,0]
B = A[(A[:, -len(target):] == target).all(axis=1)]
print(B)
# [[0 1 0]
#  [5 1 0]]
```

**Explanation**

```
print(A[:, -len(target):])
# [[1 0]
#  [0 1]
#  [1 0]]
print(A[:, -len(target):] == target)
# [[ True  True]
#  [False False]
#  [ True  True]]
print((A[:, -len(target):] == target).all(axis=1))
# [ True False  True]
```